Win10: UI elements get drawn progressively slower over time
I've had this bug for several years, and according to my memory it has followed me across multiple installs and hardware changes. As my windows session drags on, UI elements from most applications will begin to take more and more time to be displayed on the screen. It is particularly noticeable for applications that have a rich GUI such as notepad++ or the Task Manager. Killing explorer.exe will greatly reduce the intensity of the problem. Restarting my computer clears it entirely for a moment. This video demonstrates the issue.
Other similar issues are commonly occurring and also increase as my session time drags on:

Spikes of low framerate when doing everyday tasks (I have a RTX4090 and 144fps monitors)
Black rectangles being drawn for tenth of seconds on the screen (one can be seen at 10s in the video above)
UI elements being replaced by black rectangles briefly, sometimes flickering, when playing a video or switching the background picture

My specs:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X
GPU: RTX 4090
Motherboard: PRO X670-P WIFI
Memory: 64GB of DDR5
Win ver: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 21H2 build 19044.4651

What I've explored so far:

There is no performance issue reported by the task manager/perfmon ever. My RAM, CPU, GPU, Disk I/O are always way lower than their respective limits as these graphical glitch occur or as the framerate goes down. Nothing indicates a ram leak.
There seems to be a correlation between the number of GDI objects held by explorer.exe and the severity of the issue. At startup, explorer.exe will typically hold ~200 GDI objects. As my session continues, it can easily grow to ~5000 when idling. These go away when I restart the process.
I am suspicious of some software, considering the issue has persisted after entirely upgrading my computer.

Directory Opus, a replacement for the windows explorer
Sharex
Spotify



